# Cakephp Auth component behaviour for REST API call

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, postman

I am trying to implement an api_login function.
I have two functions in my UsersController for logging in
1)Login

```
public function login() {
    if($this->request->is('post') && AuthComponent::user('id') == null) {
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
    }
    else if(AuthComponent::user('id') != null){
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'controls'));
    }
}
```

and 2) api_login

```
public function api_login() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Auth->login()) {
                $message = 'success';
                $this->set(array('message' => $message, '_serialize' => 'message'));
            }
            else {
                $message = 'fail';
                $this->set(array('message' => $message, '_serialize' => 'message'));
            }
        }
    }
```

The **`login`** function works fine. But I have issues with **`api_login`**
When I use a REST client like POSTMAN, I POST requests to `http://myProject/api/users/login.json`, i cannot log in(shows 'fail' everytime) I try to post and log in using the correct credentials.

the fileds i post are username: and password:. I dont understand what i am doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
If i am missing something to describe the problem fully, please ask.

Comment: Are you getting proper values of "$this->request->data" for both of your functions. Try to print_r request data before Auth login and compare your results if they are same or not. Whatever values you get for your login function, same values should be printed for api_kogin function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your post data in login to check username and password

```
if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data))
```

Hope this helps you